# Find the maximum value of $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_nx_1$

Tags: maxima-minima

Find the maximum value of $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_nx_1$ if $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0$ and $x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2=1$.

I can get by Cauchy-Schwarz that $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_nx_1 \leqslant 1$, but can expression $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+\cdots+x_nx_1$ be smaller?

Comment: Hint: you can use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: It's a very hard Fan's inequality.

Comment: The answer is $\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Ky Fan got this result in 1955.

Comment: What is your expression when $n=4$, is it $x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_1$, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the Ky Fan-Tausski-Todd inequality or a special case of the discrete Wirtinger's inequality. The proof is not that hard, but requires an ingenious change of variables. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1467.pdf) for the complete proof and other details.